# jquery transverse to get children within a child

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble on figuring out the best way to transverse from the `form` as the origin and find the inputs that are *within a child*.

Heres my form:

```
<form class="ajax-submit-createuser clr mrg-btm-med" method="post" action="./createuser.php">
  <table class="fixed">
    <tr>
      <td><p>Enter Username</p></td>
      <td><input name="formName" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Enter Email Address</p></td>
      <td><input name="formEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="off" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Enter Password</p></td>
      <td><input name="formPass" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="off" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button class="trg-createuser btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Create</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have tried:

```
var formname = $(this).closest("input[name=formName]").val();
```

and

```
var formname = $(this).siblings().siblings("input[name=formName]").val();
var formname = $(this).siblings().siblings().siblings("input[name=formName]").val();
```

But they don't seem to work, what is the best way of transversing like this?

Comment: From where you need to traverse?

Comment: how abaout a .find() ?

Comment: @AbeCodes , if I were to use find, any other form with the same `input[name]` would be picked up too?

Comment: @FileParts yes, it will find all and make an array out of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()`. Assuming `this` refers to the `form` element, try this:

```
var formname = $(this).find("input[name=formName]").val();
```

For reference, `closest()` will find the nearest parent element matching the given selector. `siblings()` is used to find elements with the same parent as the current, it does not go up/down the DOM at all.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Although `find()` works, wouldn't this become an issue if I were, for example, to have multiple forms with the same `input[name]`. Wouldn't it also get the values from those inputs rather than the closest ones?

Comment: No, that would be fine as `find()` only looks for elements within the primary selector (in this case the `form`).

Comment: Thanks! I was worried it would grab everything :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form.ajax-submit-createuser").find('input[name=formName]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this).children("input") to get the form children of the type input.

https://api.jquery.com/children/